# How to use fade in fade out to Background image in android..?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to know how to give fade in fade out animation to android:background image. i want to use two or more images and give this animation. pls . how can I do that. in any layout..?

cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set animation to the layout

You can provide fade_in or fad_out animation to the layout

to set fade_in to layout use the following code

```
Animation mAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
layout.startAnimation(mAnim);
```

to set fade_out to layout use the following code

```
Animation mAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        layout.startAnimation(mAnim);
```